# How to show a link in HTML page which is stored in database using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a link saved in my database and I want to show that link in an HTML page. When someone clicks on the link, it should open a new tab to download a PDF file. I know how to assign a link directly in HTML. But I don't know how to do it programmatically. My link is stored in the label_link column.

HTML File

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Download"></asp:Label>
```

C# File

```
con.Open();
string str = "select * from label_update where label_counter=0 or label_counter=1";
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(str, con);
SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read();        
string a = reader["label_counter"].ToString();
if (a == "1")
{
    Label1.Text = reader["label_message"].ToString();
    Label2.Text = reader["label_link"].ToString();
}
con.Close();
```

Here I want to show the link which is stored in label_link column in Label2. When some one clicks it, it should open in a new tab.

Comment: Try using the correct control: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use a HTML anchor tag with `runat="server"` on it and assign the link in your codebehind:

```
<a runat="server" Id="lnkDownload" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

When you fetch the values from your database, assign the link to the anchor tag:

```
lnkDownload.Attributes.Add("href", url);
```

Another way is to use the asp.net built in [Hyperlink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control to produce the same result:

```
<asp:HyperLink id="hypDownload" 
                  NavigateUrl="#"
                  Text="Download"
                  Target="_blank"
                  runat="server"/> 

hypDownload.NavigateUrl = url;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Hyperlink control:

```
 <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server">DownLoad</asp:HyperLink>

 HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = "C:\\temp\\MyFile.pdf";
```